# How to make pdf with 0width left right mergin containing maximum number of ppt/odt slides?

Tags: pdf, slideshow

In our university students print the slides followed by their course teachers for using reference sheet. They put 4 slides per page for minimizing cost. I noticed that there is enough space to put 6 slides per page, because of the margin and distance between two slides take large space. The procedure they followed may be wrong. But, I don't worry about their procedure.

I know that in LaTeX we can easily change the margin width and distance between two object. So,I want to make `pdf` from these slides (as usual `ppt`,sometimes `odt`), so that I can set the margin and distance as my choice.

How can I do this?

**EDIT**
I have known the procedure to include multiple pdf pages ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3mm,right=3mm,top=3mm,bottom=3mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1-6},nup=2x3,delta=3mm 3mm]{concate.pdf}
\end{document}
```

This results [this pdf](https://www.docdroid.net/BhUQM6a/printslide.pdf). I don't want to keep space in top and bottom of the page, but this keep space. How can I solve this problem? The source pdf is [here](https://www.docdroid.net/hTf3dwC/concate.pdf).

Comment: I don't think you can insert a PPT/ODT in a LaTeX document, but if you convert them to PDF first, then you can use for example the `pdfpages` package to arrange multiple slides per sheet.

Comment: Change the `delta` values? If you say exactly what kind of layout you want (perhaps even make a sketch in Paint or similar), I'm sure someone can help.

Comment: Please add code to your question. And edit the text of your question as well, to include the description of what you want to do (which still isn't entirely clear to me, as I'm a bit slow). It's best if people doesn't have to read the comments to fully understand the problem.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I edited the question.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[margin=0pt,paperheight=24cm,paperwidth=21cm]{geometry}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo this doesn't keep unused space, but does it ensure a4paper? When I print the print operator provide me a4paper.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the unused space?  Change the aspect ratio of the slides to fit?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

This adjusts the size of the slides to fit the page precisely (including gaps).  Rather than keep track of rows and columns, it was easier to use `\ifcase` on the frame/page count.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3mm,right=3mm,top=3mm,bottom=3mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength{\slideheight}
\setlength{\slideheight}{\dimexpr \textheight -6mm}
\divide\slideheight by 3
\newlength{\slidewidth}
\setlength{\slidewidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth -3mm}
\divide\slidewidth by 2
\newcount\slide
\newcount\frame
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
\lineskip=3mm minus 0.1mm
\slide=0
\frame=0
\loop\ifnum\slide<6
  \advance\slide by 1
  \includegraphics[page=\slide,height=\slideheight,width=\slidewidth]{concat.pdf}%
  \advance\frame by 1
  \ifcase\frame% 0 never happens
    \or\hskip 3mm% 1 top left
    \or\linebreak% 2 top right
    \or\hskip 3mm% 3 middle left
    \or\linebreak% 4 middle right
    \or\hskip 3mm% 5 bottom left
    \or\pagebreak\frame=0% 6 bottom right
  \fi
\repeat
\end{document}
```

Comment: your answer is so broad to me. I guess it is possible to do same things with less code.

Comment: I suspect that pdfpages uses even more complicated code, it is just hidden in the .sty file.